# URL Builder/Text manipulation - JavaSctipt/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am so close to achieving what I want but something aint right.

My code:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $('#open').click(function() {
        var fixedData1 = 'http://10.1.1.0:3000/dashboard/db/dashboard-test?var-vip1=',
            userEntry1 = $('#one').val(),
            fixedData2 = '&var-vip2=',
            fixedData3 = '&var-nsPathSplice=',
            check = userEntry1.replace('.dfw.', '.dal.')
        var nsPathSplice = "/" + userEntry1.split(".").slice(1, 4).reverse().join("/") + "/BOM*";
        if (check == userEntry1) {
            check = userEntry1.replace('.dal.', '.dfw.')
        }
        var newWindow = window.open(fixedData1 + userEntry1 + fixedData2 + check + fixedData3 + nsPathSplice);
    })
});
```

Where userEntry1 = $('#one').val(), = the input from the user

So I am trying to build a URL string including three bits of key information from some text entered on a web form. For example, a user can enter;

**app.prod.platform.org.dal.prod.site.com-HTTP_80tcp-00000000-lb**

My snippet should then form the following URL output

http://10.0.0.0:0000/dashboard/db/dashboard-test?var-vip1=app.prod.platform.org.dal.prod.site.com-HTTP_80tcp-00000000-lb?var-vip2=app.prod.platform.org.dfw.prod.site.com-HTTP_80tcp-00000000-lb&var-nsPathSplice=/org/platform/prod/BOM*

However I am getting

http://10.0.0.0:0000/dashboard/db/dashboard-test?var-vip1=http:%2F%2F10.0.0.0:0000%2Fdashboard%2Fdb%2Fdashboard-test%3Fvar-vip1%3D&var-vip2=app.prod.platform.org.dfw.prod.site.com-HTTP_80tcp-00000000-lb&var-nsPathSplice=%2Forg%2Fplatform%2Fprod%2FBOM*

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: can you please check/debug the value of  $('#one').val(); before it's further use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $('#open').click(function() {
        var fixedData1 = 'http://10.1.1.0:3000/dashboard/db/dashboard-test?var-vip1=',
            userEntry1 = $('#one').val(),
            fixedData2 = '&var-vip2=',
            fixedData3 = '&var-nsPathSplice=',
            check = userEntry1.replace('.dfw.', '.dal.')
        var nsPathSplice = '/' + userEntry1.split('.').slice(1, 4).reverse().join('/') + '/BOM*';
        if (check == userEntry1) {
            check = userEntry1.replace('.dal.', '.dfw.')
        }
        var newWindow = window.open(fixedData1 + userEntry1 + fixedData2 + check + fixedData3 + nsPathSplice);
    })
});
```

I tried the above code in [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vtkcc410/), which is working as required.
thanks